# How do I add localizations to my node environment so tests match browser behaviour?

Tags: node.js, internationalization, jsdom

I'm writing a test of our formatting functions that use the JS i18n API.

```
(5).toLocaleString('en-ca', {style: 'currency', currency: 'CAD'})
```

In the browser I get `$5.00`, as I would expect.

In the jest tests (node 8.9.1 + jsdom), I get `CA$5.00`.

It should be `$5.00` since the specified locale is Canada. `CA$5.00` would make sense if the locale was `'en-us'`, thus specifying a foreign currency.

This behaviour seems to differ across ECMAscript implmentations. Testing so far reveals:

- jest/jsdom/node *always* adds CA to CAD
- Chrome, Safari and Firefox only add it if the locale is not set to Canada
- IE *never* adds it.

For `fr-ca` the differences are even bigger:

```
(5).toLocaleString('fr-ca', {style: 'currency', currency: 'CAD'})
\\ node: `CA$ 5.00` (incorrect). 
\\ browser: `5,00 $` (correct)
```

I suspect that whatever environment the tests are running in (presumably my nvm managed version of node) has no localization for 'fr-ca', or possibly any localizations at all outside of `en-US`. I would like to have our tests match the browsers so they can... test.

Comment: I updated the question with some clarifications. in Canada (similar to every other country) we call out foreign prices and not local prices. Although i've always seen it written as USD/CAD not CA$/US$ like javascript does.